# Ordering a set without duplication in JAVA

Tags: java, treeset

I need to order a set without duplicating it in memory, using a custom comparator.

The naive implementation would be:

```
Set<MyClass> newSet = new TreeSet<>(myComparator);
newSet.addAll(oldSet);
```

but this would imply that, even for a limited time, I'll have two sets in memory: oldSet (unordered) and newSet(ordered). Since they will be very large, I would like to avoid this.

I would like to perform something like this:

```
oldSet = new TreeSet<>(oldSet, myComparator);
```

which actually is not possible, since there is no constructor for TreeSet with such structure.

Could this be a solution?

```
Iterator<MyClass> it = oldSet.iterator();
Set<MyClass> newSet = new TreeSet<>(myComparator);
while(it.hasNext())
{
    newSet.add(it.next());
    it.remove();
}
```

Something better to suggest?

Thank you

Comment: @kai Without `it.remove()` OP will have two full sets in memory at once, which is the problem his question is about.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `TreeSet` will not be the most memory-efficient for this, and it won't even be the fastest way.

You should use an `ArrayList` and perform a sort on it:

```
List<MyClass> sorted = new ArrayList<>(oldSet.size());
oldSet = null;
Collections.sort(sorted, myComparator);
```

The overhead of a single array used inside `ArrayList` should not be an issue, and in any case it is the smallest issue you can have.

The single-shot bulk sort operation is faster than finding the right place for each individual item in a `TreeSet`, along with all the allocation needed in that case.

Comment: well i would expect `n log n` for both the bulk Collection.sort (mergesort) and the TreeSet insertions (n insertions each at log n)

Comment: @guido It's the constant factors, not abstract complexity.

Comment: if you grow concerns about constant factors for sorting an array in memory, you should check your infrastructure.. :) just chitchatting, actually I would have proposed the same answer, which i like, if you didn't already, so you get my +1

Comment: maybe, just except the fact that your end up with an object that does not implement SortedSet, but was not a requirement here

Comment: @guido The way I have read the question, OP's main concern is getting the items sorted. I assume that otherwise he would have the `TreeSet` from the start. My comment on constant factors: is it the same to play a game at 100 FPS vs. 10 FPS? :)

Answer (score 0):

As a `Set` is not ordered by definition, there is no way to order a `Set`, so (as you do it) you have to use an ordered data structure. However you do not need to care about the problem you see at all, Java will not perform a deep copy of the `Set` if you perform `addAll`, it will just copy references which uses nearly no RAM.

So your `addAll` Solution is a clean and correct one.

Comment: "As a `Set` is not ordered by definition, there is no way to order a `Set`" No, a `Set` in Java is only unordered unless specified otherwise. The contract for `SortedSet` (of which `TreeSet` is an implementation) guarantees that the items have a well-defined order.

Comment: @Smallhacker I was talking about a Set, if you have a Set it is not ordered, period. A TreeSet is a special Set that changes this behaviour

Comment: Ah, so you meant it as "there is no way to order a Set _that isn't already ordered_"? Okay, my bad then.

Answer (score 0):

If you can null all the references to the old set do it

```
newSet.addAll(oldSet);
oldSet = null;
```

if you cannot null all the references to the old set use Set.clear method

```
newSet.addAll(oldSet);
oldSet.clear();
```

note that after clear HashSet's inner hashtable does not shrink

Comment: The hashtable may stay, but all the `Map.Entry`s will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a set with set in constructor, you create swallow copy. You copy only references. When you delete you delete references too. It is visible in the code below:

```
MyComparator myComparator = new MyComparator();
Set<Object> newSet = new TreeSet<>(myComparator);
Object mc = new Object();
newSet.add(mc); //set is created

Set<Object> newerSet = new TreeSet<>(myComparator);
newerSet.addAll(newSet);
System.out.println(newSet);
System.out.println(newerSet);
```

Output:
[java.lang.Object@1bb1deea]
[java.lang.Object@1bb1deea]

Reference to the same object.

```
newerSet.remove(mc);
System.out.println("After deletion");
System.out.println(newSet);
System.out.println(newerSet);
```

After deletion
[java.lang.Object@1bb1deea]
[]

Only reference is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You should write an `Iterator` implementation where each call to `next()` give you the next sorted item. It won't take no additional memory, but the amount of additional memory will be small compared to duplicating the unordered `Set`. You also won't have a new `Set`, but you will be able to iterate through it.

A low-memory version, but inefficient algorithm would store the most recently accessed item in the `Iterator`. Every time you needed to return the next item, you'd go through all the items in the backing `Set` to figure out which was next.